# Do I need to move external libraries with my application for each device

Tags: c#, .net

In order to use an external library in my C# project we need to add it as an assembly reference in form of dll files as the pic below:
[image]
but by this way, do I need to put the dll files along with my application in each machine I move my app? or they will be embedded in my application and so no need to always carry them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either copy references with the project, [embed the libraries as resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452114/how-do-package-managed-c-sharp-dlls-with-a-managed-c-sharp-application-without-l), or use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630) to generate one large executable.  However unless you have a STRONG reason to NOT copy the reference assemblies I would stick with the standard practice of copying the referenced assemblies.  (wanting to have just one file for simplicity is not a strong reason to me).

Framework (`System.*`) libraries will be installed in the GAC on the target machine so you won't have to deploy them.

Any non-system libraries will either need to be installed in the GAC (ether by you or by a 3rd party installer for their libraries) or copied with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For that there's a property within your reference properties window called `Copy Local`. If this property is set to true, the reference is copied to the output path of the project at run time.

[image]