# How to bundle a required DLL with a solution in Visual C# (Express, 2010)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have an application written in C# which interfaces with some custom hardware using a vendor supplied .Net assembly. The .Net assembly in turn loads another DLL at run time. I can add the vendor supplied assembly to my project but when I run it, the vendor assembly complains that it can't load the required DLL. I can work around this for the moment by copying the DLL to the bin\Debug and bin\Release folder.

The problem is that I will need to distribute this application to clients at some point and they will not have this DLL in place. I can't see how I can make the solution require it; I can't add it as a reference since I get the error ***"A reference to foo.dll could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."***

I can't convert the DLL to a .Net assembly using TlbExp, it gives an error "***The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest."***

I thought if I published the application via "click once" that I could declare the dependency there but I don't see any way for this either. I also tried adding it as a file resource but this didn't seem to help.

I can see other questions on SO relating to how to invoke functionality in an external DLL but in this case, I just need a way to bundle the DLL with the project.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try creating a Windows Installer through Visual studio and bundling the DLL in that

Comment: Thanks, reviewing this it seems that the option for creating an installer is not provided with Express Edition (I've updated the question to clarify that I'm using express).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indicates that the attributed method is exposed by an unmanaged dynamic-link library (`DLL`)

The `DllImportAttribute` attribute provides the information needed to call a function exported from an unmanaged `DLL`. As a minimum requirement, you must supply the name of the DLL containing the entry point.

For further reference go here
[Link to Review](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but the question doesn't relate to how to invoke the unmanaged code, this is already handled by the vendor supplied assembly. The problem is that the vendor supplied assembly expects to find the unmanaged DLL and I can't see a way of bundling this with the application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452114/how-do-package-managed-c-sharp-dlls-with-a-managed-c-sharp-application-without-l

Comment: Have you tried above thread in SO? If not, please check the answer section, I guess it might be help you

Comment: Thanks, I had not seen that thread before and it looks like it might solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the dll as a resource, write it out as a `byte[]` to a file on loading, and do an `Assembly.Load()`  at runtime for deployment.

You might have to use an `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve Event` to make sure the assembly resolves in case of multiple versions.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the right kind of direction. Ramesh Muthiah below links to another thread where it talks about doing this without having to create a temporary file (if I have understood it correctly).

Comment: @PhilDin I'd used this logic in several applications where I had the same problem and never had any issues with it. The loading from ManifestResourceStream is a cleaner solution though...Will have to try it out

Answer (score 0):

you could add both (all) of the dlls in your project as references and mark them as "copy local". That should do it unless the first DLL expects the second DLL in a specific place.

Comment: Thanks but I get an error when I try to add the second DLL as a reference so I don't think this is an option.